# AHardwareBuffer_lock is insanely slow; takes 25ms+

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera2

I'm trying to get an `android.media.Image`'s raw pixel content to the CPU. I wanted to use `HardwareBuffer`s for this as it seems like those are the direct GPU memory frames, but it turns out they are **10x** slower than just reading the `ByteBuffer`s from each Plane!

I've investigated these two approaches:

1. Using `getPlanes()[i].getBuffer()`:

   ```java
   private static ByteBuffer byteArrayCache;

   public ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() {
       switch (image.getFormat()) {
           case ImageFormat.YUV_420_888:
               ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
               ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
               ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
               int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
               int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
               int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();
               int totalSize = ySize + uSize + vSize;

               if (byteArrayCache != null) byteArrayCache.rewind();
               if (byteArrayCache == null || byteArrayCache.remaining() != totalSize) {
                   byteArrayCache = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(totalSize);
               }

               byteArrayCache.put(yBuffer).put(uBuffer).put(vBuffer);

               return byteArrayCache;
           case ImageFormat.JPEG:
               return image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
           default:
               throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert Frame to byte[]!");
       }
   ```

   Then, in C++/NDK:

   ```cpp
   jni::local_ref<JByteBuffer> buffer = javaPart_->toByteBuffer(); // fbjni call
   uint8_t* data = buffer->getDirectAddress();
   size_t size = buffer->getDirectSize();

   // copy the data from this Frame into a separate recycled buffer so it lives longer
   auto destinationBuffer = myCachedCppBuffer;
   memcpy(destinationBuffer, (void*)data, sizeof(uint8_t) * size);
   ```
2. Using `AHardwareBuffer`:

   ```java
   private HardwareBuffer hardwareBufferCache;

   private Object getHardwareBuffer() {
       if (hardwareBufferCache == null) hardwareBufferCache = image.getHardwareBuffer();
       return hardwareBufferCache;
   }

   private void close() {
       hardwareBufferCache.close()
   }
   ```

   Then, in C++/NDK:

   ```cpp
   AHardwareBuffer* buffer = javaPart_->getHardwareBuffer(); // fbjni call

   AHardwareBuffer_Desc description;
   AHardwareBuffer_describe(buffer, &description);
   size_t size = description.height * description.stride;

   void* data;
   int fence = -1;
   AHardwareBuffer_lock(buffer, AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_CPU_READ_MASK, fence, nullptr, &data);

   // copy the data from this Frame into a separate recycled buffer so it lives longer
   memcpy(destinationBuffer, data, sizeof(uint8_t) * size);
   AHardwareBuffer_unlock(buffer, &fence);
   ```

I thought that HardwareBuffers are supposed to be the direct GPU memory (i.e. an OpenGL TEXTURE_2D/EGLImageKHR) and therefore should be faster. Instead, they were significantly slower:

For calling those methods a hundred times with 3840x2160 PRIVATE Frames:

1. `getPlanes()[i].getBuffer()` took **~2ms** on average
2. `getHardwareBuffer()` took **~25ms** on average

Any ideas why?